# Spacing of child components in Bulma and React

Tags: reactjs, jsx, bulma

I am struggling to get the correct padding of some form fields using React and Bulma.
I want to build a password field React component where render looks like that:

```
    <div className="field">
      <div className="field has-addons">
        <p className="control has-icons-left is-expanded">
          <input
            className="input"
            type={passwordFieldType}
            placeholder="Passwort"
            value={props.value}
            required={true}
            onChange={e => props.update(e.target.value)}
          />
          <span className="icon is-small is-left">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faLock} />
          </span>
        </p>
        <p className="control">
          <a
              className="button"
              onClick={() => setPasswordVisible(!passwordVisible)}>
            <span className="icon is-small is-right">
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={passwordVisibleIcon} />
            </span>
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
      {props.children}
    </div>
```

I've added a progress bar that indicates the password strength as a child component:

```
    <PasswordField value={password} update={props.update}>
      <progress
        className={`progress is-small ${passwordIndicatorColor}`}
        max={MAX_PASSWORD_SCORE}
        value={passwordScore}
      />
      {props.children}
    </PasswordField>
```

The component is then used together with an Email field and a box to create the registration view:

[image: Current form]

This is close to what I want, the only problem is that the the progress bar is too far away from the password field. I've tried to change the top margin of the progress bar to 0, as described here: https://bulma.io/documentation/helpers/spacing-helpers/, but it didn't do anything.

Here is a mockup of what I aim for:

[image: Intended form]

How can I get the pasword field and progress bar closer together?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add **mb-0** to the field definition as described in the [Bulma spacing documentation](https://bulma.io/documentation/helpers/spacing-helpers/):

```
    <div className="field">
      <div className="field has-addons mb-0">
        <p className="control has-icons-left is-expanded">
          <input
            className="input"
            type={passwordFieldType}
            placeholder="Passwort"
            value={props.value}
            required={true}
            onChange={e => props.update(e.target.value)}
          />
          <span className="icon is-small is-left">
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faLock} />
          </span>
        </p>
        <p className="control">
          <a
              className="button"
              onClick={() => setPasswordVisible(!passwordVisible)}>
            <span className="icon is-small is-right">
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={passwordVisibleIcon} />
            </span>
          </a>
        </p>
      </div>
      {props.children}
    </div>
```

I already tried that before, but misread the documentation and tried **margin-bottom-0** instead of **mb-0**.